# Time-complexity set-car! / set-cdr! in scheme

Tags: scheme, time-complexity, sicp

I'm wondering what time-complexity set-car! and set-cdr! has in Scheme? I would think it's constant time, but I might be wrong as I don't know how they work internally. Anyone who has an idea?

Comment: This would be implementation dependent, because it isn't specified "how they work internally."  I would expect, as you do, that it would be constant time in most implementations.

Comment: I'd find it remarkable if a Scheme implementation somehow managed to implement these in such a way that they were *not* constant time.

Comment: @AlexisKing There's the classic (educational) implementation of `cons` in terms of closures.  If lexical closures weren't implemented well, then set-cdr and set-car could be slower there.  Granted, I don't expect an implementation to provide those as the actual implementation, but I could see it being the case in an example implementation.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It could be slower, but it'd still be constant time, albeit with a greater constant factor.

Comment: @chris it would still depend on how lexical environments were implemented. If those were implemented as Association lists, then it could easily be rather slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any sensible implementation of Scheme, since conses are so common, they're implemented as some kind of double-word structure. In such implementations, `car`, `cdr`, `set-car!`, and `set-cdr!` are all constant-time.

As Alexis King commented, you'd have to have a pretty perverse implementation for it not to be constant time. (e.g., if cons cells were implemented as alists.)

Comment: The only reason for not having constant time is that you are emulating arrays/direct memory lookup. I think shlisp is one, my Zozotez another.